# android ImageView scaling to fit another View

Tags: android-layout, scaling, android-imageview

I have a relative layout that comprises a TextView and an ImageView:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

What I want to achieve is:

[image]

It means that I want my ImageView to scale to fit the TextView by height. Can it be done in xml, without java-coding?
If I could write something like

```
android:layout_height="match_that_TextView"
```

it would solve this issue, but it's impossible I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Make fix height in RelativeLayout

Comment: I would not like to use magic numbers. I want ImageView's height to depend on TextView's height.

Comment: then only programmatically get size item TextView and set height ImageView.